# ORA-00001 unique constraint - with valid value

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

We are having an issue inserting a record into a table in our oracle database.

The insert is being done through VB.NET. The table itself has no primary key, and has two unique indexes.

The two unique indexes are an integer (maintained by an oracle sequence) and a char field (which is a calculation based off a second sequence).

When trying to insert a record, we are getting the 'ORA-00001' error as a result. Stepping through the code, it first gets the two sequence nextvals (after which I can see that they did indeed increment), then runs the insert query and fails. I can take the two unique index values that the insert is trying to run and query for them in the table, and get no results.

I'm not sure exactly what kind of information would be useful to help narrow down this issue, but I do know that the oracle error I'm getting back in .NET points to the integer index value.

If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to post your code

Comment: If you know they are unique and not present in the table, and each unique index constraint is being met, the only logical thing I can think of is that you're trying to execute the insert twice with the same values.

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal (but complete) database script and vb.net code that will allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The problem could be in the transaction, if you insert two of the same in the same transaction they will both be rolledback and you won't be able to see neither of them.

Comment: Well, shortly after posting this question I realized the problem. The insert query was doing an `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` and the SELECT was getting multiple rows where it should have only gotten 1. It's been rewritten to work correctly, thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you called "NEXTVAL", it increased.

If you want to insert into a table with sequence, you may find you will fail with error "unique constraint violated". However, when you tried second time, it will success, that's because sequence need check at the first time you using it.

***Here's the solution:***

**before insert, do the select query:**

select (you sequence column name) from table.

then,

insert into table value(...).

It will work.